# Overload VB's & Concatenate operator in a C# library

Tags: c#, vb.net

So I have a DLL that was implemented in VB and I've ported over to C#.  One of the features of my library was that I had a class that I tried to give the same look and feel as a string.  I overloaded string concatenation operators.

In C# the + operator is used for string concatenation, whereas in VB the & operator is used.  Therefore in the old VB version of the library I overloaded both operators.  Then VB and C# clients of the library could use it just fine.

When I port the class to C#, I still continue to overload the & operator.  However, a VB client reports that the & operator isn't implemented.  It won't compile.

Here is my C# library:

```
public class Document
{
    private readonly string _body;

    public Document(string body)
    {
        _body = body;
    }

    public static Document operator &(Document lhs, string rhs)
    {
        return new Document(string.Concat(lhs.ToString(), rhs));
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _body;
    }
}
```

And here is by VB client code, which doesn't compile.  The error message is "Operator '&' is not defined for types 'Document' and 'String'".

```
<TestMethod()>
Public Sub TestMethod1()

    Dim doc = New Document("Hello")

    doc = doc & ", world!"

End Sub
```

Does anybody know how I support VB's & concatenate operator from a C# library?

Comment: It's just this: `[SpecialName] public static Document op_Concatenate(Document lhs, string rhs)`

Comment: Yup, using the special op_Concatenate method name works.  The VB compiler recognizes this.  Unfortunately Resharper (v9.0 Update 1) mistakenly still reports this as an error.

Comment: Resharper has logged this as a bug:  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-437879